# What is google api endpoint for info tables in "Network analysis" section for VM NIC in GCP console

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, firewall

When You log in to your project on GCP via https://console.cloud.google.com You could display "Network interface details" on selected Virtual Machine. There is "Network analysis"  section there and cool tables for "Ingress analysis" and "Egress analysis". "Ingress analysis" have source IP and destination port fields calculated for VM NIC from firewall rules and network tags. Is it possible to get those "analysis" tables via API for each VM(or NIC)  ?

Goal: Write a simple script to inspect/audit firewalls in all projets inside organization.

Answer (score 1):

There are no direct metrics for firewall rules in the GCP monitoring API, but there are sub-sections of the Google Cloud metrics that you may take a particular interest in. Some of the individual metric types in these sub-sections are how the data you are referring to is available for analysis.

**Compute** metrics:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute

**Networking** metrics:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-networking

**Router** metrics:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-router

**VPC** metrics:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-vpc%20access

and **VPN** metrics:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-vpn

There are others that implicate network metrics such as [Interconnect](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-interconnect) and [Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-loadbalancing)

### firewall auditing alternative

You could always inspect firewall rules via the Cloud SDK

To list all firewall rules in a project in table form, run:

```
  gcloud beta compute firewall-rules list
```

To list the URIs of all firewall rules in a project, run:

```
  gcloud beta compute firewall-rules list --uri
```

To list all fields of all firewall rules in a project, run:

```
gcloud beta compute firewall-rules list --format="table(
          name,
          network,
          direction,
          priority,
          sourceRanges.list():label=SRC_RANGES,
          destinationRanges.list():label=DEST_RANGES,
          allowed[].map().firewall_rule().list():label=ALLOW,
          denied[].map().firewall_rule().list():label=DENY,
          sourceTags.list():label=SRC_TAGS,
          sourceServiceAccounts.list():label=SRC_SVC_ACCT,
          targetTags.list():label=TARGET_TAGS,
          targetServiceAccounts.list():label=TARGET_SVC_ACCT,
          disabled
      )"
```